# How can I use a static method in an interface to return a generic instance returned by an instance method?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

Sorry for the difficult wording of the title. I'm fumbling for words at this point. :)

I've got a bunch of different entities that are coming out of a data store and they get linked together at run time by searching.  When I need to retrieve one of them, I have the class or class name and I have the search text that is needed to find it.

I want to be able to declare the details of how to search for each object in its own class, but if the code requesting the searching doesn't know the actual type (i.e. Foo.class) then it calls a static method to handle the searching setup.
Right now, I have to cast and suppress warnings, and it doesn't feel like that should be needed.  Am I missing something simple?

```
public interface RetrievableBySearch<E extends RetrievableBySearch> extends Retrievable {
  E searchForEntity(String searchKey);

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  static <E extends RetrievableBySearch> E getEntityBySearch(Class<E> entityClass, String searchKey) {
    try {
      return (E) entityClass.newInstance().searchForEntity(searchKey);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to instantiate entityClass", e);
    }
  }
}

public class Foo implements RetrievableBySearch<Foo> {
  @Override public Foo searchForEntity(String searchKey) {
    // Do a search...
    return new Foo();
  }
}

// Elsewhere, someone has a reference to a Class<Foo>
Retrievable thing = RetrievableBySearch.getEntityBySearch(getClassForThing(), "Find this");
```

Comment: It's always helpful to list the actual error messages that you get, and where they occur.

Comment: I am not sure why generics are needed here.  Is it not enough to simply implement `RetrievableBySearch`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `RetrievableBySearch` as a raw type. You don't need the cast if you simply provide a type parameters:

```
interface RetrievableBySearch<E extends RetrievableBySearch<E>> {
    E searchForEntity(String searchKey);

    static <E extends RetrievableBySearch<E>> E getEntityBySearch(Class<E> entityClass,
            String searchKey) {
        try {
            return entityClass.newInstance().searchForEntity(searchKey);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to instantiate entityClass", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, in response to your question, you can avoid the unchecked warning and the cast if you replace the < E extends RetrievableBySearch> in both places with < E extends RetrievableBySearch< E > >.

That said, I should point out that the semantics of this class are very fishy.  The searchForEntity method suggests that the interface might be named "Searcher", not "RetreivableBySearch".  "RetreivableBySearch" doesn't sound like an interface name at all, as this implies that there is a search related contract some other class has to satisfy.  If you want to be able to look up an object by its class name and searchKey, I would suggest you make a single map of classname/searchKey tuples.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the advice.  Part of the code smell here is me attempting to take a much more complicated scenario and distilling it to something small for posting here.  That said, I believe I have worked away most of the problematic code when finding a different approach.  The search related contract is actually in each E.  The individual classes know how to query for an instance given the searchKey. Some query databases, and others query Kafka. The application gets a list of class names and search criteria and is responsible for retrieving the actual object instances.